# MacBook Pro not turning on after not being used

Tags: macbook-pro

I have stopped using my MacBook Pro (end of 2016) with touchbar for more than a month. Today I tried to boot it up but was not able to.
Before not using it, I made sure it was charged to 100% and I shut it down completely. I thought doing so would help prevent the battery from being damaged.
Unfortunately it seems the mac is dead without any reason. I have to say that when I tried to start it today, the screen lightened up, then I was able to see the login screen for 1second then nothing. I could see that it was at 1% and being charged.

I tried to leave it charging for 1 hour but still nothing.

Any idea what to do from here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Reset your SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)**. It controls the power management hardware on your system. It may not be allowing your battery to charge for a number of reasons.

If this still happens afterwards, please take a (preferably high frame rate) video of you powering on your machine, including both the keyboard and display, so that we can see at precisely which point in the boot it fails.

**EDIT:**

In our discussion in comments, we ruled out possible low-hanging fruit:

1. Ensuring the correct key chord for SMC reset (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd> on the **left-hand side** of the keyboard for pre-T2 units, + <kbd>Power</kbd>)
2. Swapping the charger cable.
3. Swapping the charger.
4. Trying all four USB-C ports.
5. Verifying live AC power.

Because of how early in the boot flow the failure occurs, it is likely to be due to a hardware issue. There’s very little you can do to debug this without poking at the hardware, whether it’s you or an Apple support engineer doing it. You would need to start probing voltages along the power rails and looking at power sequencing on an oscilloscope. Maybe it’s something as simple as a bad battery confusing SMC, in which case you could try to replace the battery yourself, but don’t buy one unless you’ve confirmed with a multimeter that yours is bad.

Short answer: Talk to Apple for options.

Comment: At this point it doesn't turn on at all. It did it once for 1 second. I will try the SMC reset and let you know.

Comment: The SMC reset didn't change anything. nothing happens, the screen doesn't show anything nor turn on

Comment: Just to confirm, which keys did you hold down?

Comment: Shift + control + option + power button for 10 seconds. I hope there is something else to try

Comment: Specifically all modifier keys on the **left side** of the keyboard, yes?

Comment: Yes that's right. I tried 2 different chargers, 2 different cables, still nothing

Comment: A couple of other dumb things I need to ask about: Did you check that the AC power outlet that you’re plugging the charger into has live current? Have you tried plugging the USB-C power cable into all four of your MBP ports?

Comment: unfortunately I already tried all 4 ports, and yes I plugged into the AC power outlet where my current computer was plugged.

Comment: I don’t have good news for you. A failure this early in boot is likely a hardware issue. There’s very little you can do to debug this without poking at the hardware, whether it’s you or an Apple support engineer doing it. You would need to start probing voltages along the power rails and looking at power sequencing on an oscilloscope. Maybe it’s something as simple as a bad battery confusing SMC, in which case you could try to replace the battery yourself, but don’t buy one unless you’ve confirmed with a multimeter that yours is bad. Short answer: Talk to Apple for options.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm unfortunately a software guy so I will have to take it to some repair shop. hopefully it will not cost much as the main purpose was to format it and sell it. Could you append this to your answer so I mark it as correct ?